# Angular filteration issue

Tags: angularjs

I have a json data which looks like this:

```
{
  "id": 355,
  "title": "ZISIMOPOULOS LTD",
  "cat": "Contractor - High Pressure, Cutting & Breaking, Hydrodemolition, Surface Preparation - UHP, Tube, Pipe & Bundle Cleaning",
  "catids": {
    "1": 17,
    "2": 18,
    "3": 21,
    "4": 26,
    "5": 27
  },
  "link": "http://wja.dev/members/zisimopoulos-ltd/",
  "memberType": "C1 - Water Jetting Contractor",
  "email": "info@zisimopoulos.gr",
  "telephone": "302104412004",
  "fax": "302104416524",
  "website": "www.zisimopoulos.gr",
  "instructor": false
}
```

Each member has catids associated to it.

Now i need the filteration function, where on clicking on the categories in the left will list the member associated to that categories.

[Filteration page layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuCr1.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome Stackoverflow!  Any code /demo, what did you do so far? please post code and examples. This site helps to solve code problems and not code factory

Comment: what do you have so far ?

Comment: I am new to Angular, I have done the other stuffs which are needed on the page like search by member type, pagination, search but I am struggling with the category filtration as each member has more and one categories associated to it. You can see here what I can don so far [link](http://wja.designbyshard.com/our-members/) Any direction will be appreciated.